# Can I manage my NixOS configuration in version control like git?

Tags: configuration, git, nixos, nix

*Long story short: I've used only distributions with "imperative configuration management/packaging" approach, so far. And,... I'm annoyed by hard to trace breakages/issues with imperative configuration management (when experimenting).*

I've found [NixOS](https://nixos.org/), which advertises:

> NixOS has a completely declarative approach to configuration management: you write a specification of the desired configuration of your system in NixOS’s modular language, and NixOS takes care of making it happen.

I'm considering to use NixOS as my main desktop operating system, and store configuration in GIT repository.

So, is NixOS configuration gittable? Can I "define" my main operating system configuration by git repository (proabbly with some "apply" commands)?

Comment: If you read up on how NixOS configuration works, you'll soon see that the only thing `git` will need to do is provide the `configuration.nix` file. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The NixOS configuration consists of two files (although you can break it up into more files): `configuration.nix` and `hardware-configuration.nix`.

Both files are stored in `/etc/nixos` and they are text files. Hence, you can certainly put them in a GIT repo.